Clarifying a remark by Herstein in his proof on conjugates of a and right cosets of N(a)
I don't understand why $y=nx$ in the below proof.
I was wondering if it is always the case that if two elements from a group are in the same right coset, then you can reach the other by composing an element from the coset with one, or if this is a specific property of the normalizer.
Theorem 2.H. If $G$ is a finite group, then $c_a = \frac{o(G)}{o(N(a))}$; in other words, the number of elements conjugate to $a$ in $G$ is the index of the normalizer of $a$ in $G$.
Proof (abbrevated for relevant section): Suppose that $x, y \in G$ are in the same right coset of $N(a)$ in $G.$ Thus $y=nx$ where $n\in N(a)$, and so $na = an.$ Therefore, since $y^{-1} = (nx)^{-1} = x^{-1}n^{-1}, y^{-1}ay = x^{-1}n^{-1}anx = x^{-1}n^{-1}nax = x^{-1}ax$, whence $x$ and $y$ result in the same conjugate of $a.$ (p. 71 in the first edition of Topics of Algebra)
Thank you!

Let $H$ be any subgroup of the group $G$. If $x \in Ha$ then $x=ha$ for some $h \in H$.  Likewise, if $y \in Ha$ then $y=h'a$ for some $h'\in H$.  Then $y = h'a = h' h^{-1}x$.  So yes, you can reach $y$ by multipyling $x$ with an element of $H$.  (This argument worked with no assumptions on the subgroup $H$, so normalizers have nothing to do with it.)

Thank you, so just to check my understanding: he then writes "If, on the other hand, $x$ and $y$ are in different right cosets of $N(a)$ in $G$ we claim that $x^{-1}ax \neq y^{-1}ay.$ Were this not the case, from $x^{-1}ax = y^{-1}ay$ we would deduce that $yx^{-1}a = ayx^{-1}$; this would in turn imply that $yx^{-1} \in N(a).$ However, this declares $x$ and $y$ to be in the same right coset of $N(a)$ in $G$..." I think that this means if $yx^{-1} \in N(a)$, then there is a certain $g$ for which $x=ng$ for any $n$ and $y=ng$ for any $n$? I am still trying to work out how I would show this.

That is just as easy to prove as what I did.  This is just part of the basic "yoga" of cosets:  $x,y \in Ha$ if and only if $xy^{-1} \in H$.  Exercise.

To wit:  $x=h_1a$ and $y=h_2a$ implies that $xy^{-1}=h_1h_2^{-1}$, which belongs to $H$.

Would proving the backwards direction look like $xy^{-1}a \in Ha$ $\Rightarrow$ $xy^{-1}aa^{-1} \in Ha$ $\Rightarrow$ $xy^-1 \in Ha$ $\Rightarrow$ (a) $x \in Ha$, (b) $y^{-1} \in Ha$ $\Rightarrow$ $y \in Ha$?

I can't follow that.  I think you have extraneous $a$'s in there.  For instance, you should assume $xy^{-1} \in H$, not $xy^{-1}a \in Ha$.

Oh, I understand your explanation. Thank you so much!

Why the downvote?  What’s wrong?
